# Laravel Validation: use laravel required and if exists together

Tags: validation, laravel-7

I have the following validation requirement.

if inventory_purchase_bill == True, lines.*.sku should be
required|exists:items,sku if inventory_purchase_bill == False,
lines.*.sku should be nullable|exists:items,sku

Basically test for exists only if there is a value. If no value or null then, don't check for exists.

Tried following, but second-line overrides first. How to achieve this?

```
$validation = $this->validate($request, [
            'inventory_purchase_bill' => 'required',
            'lines.*.sku' => 'exclude_unless:inventory_purchase_bill,false|nullable|exists:items,sku',            
            'lines.*.sku' => 'exclude_unless:inventory_purchase_bill,true|required|exists:items,sku',            
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'lines.*.sku' =>  function($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
                if ($request->bill_type == 'Stock Purchase') {
                    if($value !=null && $value != ''){
                        $item = Item::where('sku',$value)->first();
                        if($item == null){
                            return $fail($value.' not in database. Please add new item.');
                        }
                    }else{
                        return $fail('SKU is required.');
                    }
                }
                if ($request->bill_type == 'Expense') {
                    if($value !=null && $value != ''){
                        $item = Item::where('sku',$value)->first();
                        if($item == null){
                            return $fail($value.' not in database. Please add new item.');
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```